# Hiding a specific button via Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a form, in which there are several buttons.
Using Jquery i have to hide a specific button. I am able to get all the buttons via `$( ":button")` 
But i am not able to locate the button and hence unable to hide.

Below is the source code of that button :

```
<td nowrap="">
    <button id="s_3_1_20_0_Ctrl" class="appletButton" 
      aria-label="Line Items:View Supplier Notes" 
      title="Line Items:View Supplier Notes" tabindex="0" 
      data-display="View Supplier Notes" type="button" 
      style="visibility: visible;"> … </button>
</td>
```

Comment: how do you know which button has to be hidden

Comment: [I'm guessing you don't have a lot of experience with jQuery?](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways of doing this:

```
$("#s_3_1_20_0_Ctrl").hide();

$("#s_3_1_20_0_Ctrl").css("display","none");
```

If you want to toggle between seeing and not seeing the button you could use any of the above (but alter such as .css("display","block"); ) or you could use:

```
$("#s_3_1_20_0_Ctrl").toggle()
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try with:

```
jQuery("#s_3_1_20_0_Ctrl").hide()
```

??

Comment: What happened to the format of the question?? I've adjusted it and now it's gone...

Answer (score 1):

Not seeing your code, but typically you'll want to give that button an ID, and then you can 
hide it via

```
$('#myID').hide()
```

See http://api.jquery.com/id-selector

Comment: Is there any other way than to use id here ? 
Problem is id changes everytime, if the pages reloaded again. Because some of the views are getting displayed dynamically.

Comment: @ak0053792 You can use DOM traversal methods to find the button relative to some other button. If you show the HTML and explain the criteria for determining which button to hide, we can probably give a more detailed answer.

Comment: You could possibly give the button you want to hide a custom class, and select by that.
http://api.jquery.com/class-selector

Or you could get (say) the 3rd button from your $(':button') selector. Or if the buttons are getting written out by a server-side language such as ASP, you could have that write the generated ID into the javascript call to hide the button.

Comment: Thanks. I am new to this forum. And the response is very positive. Thanks all. I am having a feeling that i will learn alot of things with all of your help. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

give that button an id like `id="blah"`

then in your script

```
$('#blah').hide();
```